# Multiple div's bind to JQuery function - function invoked multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of div's. This is one div structure:

```
<div class="commentWrap" id="@Model.CommentId">
        <p id="commentTextValue">@Model.CommentText</p>
        <a id="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
</div>
```

I want to attach action for each edit button in div's. I separate div's by div id. This is JQuery function when I click on edit button:

```
$('#editButton').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var container = $(this).closest('div');
    var itemId = container.attr('id');
    alert(itemId);
})
```

And it works. It display correct ID of element.
Problem is when I have more than one div. For example when I have 5 div's and click on some edit button alert message is displayed 5 times???
What I did wrong here?

```
<div id="messages">


    <div style="border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); ">
        <a href="/Comment/SomeAction">Vlada Vucetic</a> 467327
        <div class="commentWrap" id="467327">
            <p class="commentTextValue">test 4</p>
            <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); ">
        <a href="/Comment/SomeAction">Vlada Vucetic</a> 980339
        <div class="commentWrap" id="980339">
            <p class="commentTextValue">test 3</p>
            <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); ">
        <a href="/Comment/SomeAction">Vlada Vucetic</a> 166111
        <div class="commentWrap" id="166111">
            <p class="commentTextValue">test 2</p>
            <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-right-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-bottom-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); border-left-color: rgb(221, 221, 221); ">
        <a href="/Comment/SomeAction">Vlada Vucetic</a> 769630
        <div class="commentWrap" id="769630">
            <p class="commentTextValue">test 1</p>
            <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do all of you anchors have the same id `editButton`? If so, I am not surprised at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. Replace `id` with `class`, and `#` with a dot.

```
<div class="commentWrap" id="@Model.CommentId">
        <p class="commentTextValue">@Model.CommentText</p>
        <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
</div>

$('.editButton').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var container = $(this).closest('div');
    var itemId = container.attr('id');
    alert(itemId);
})
```

Comment: I did this but it doesn't work :( If I click on one item from 5 of them with id 45678 it display me alert '45678' 5 times.

Comment: Did you make sure that the each ID is **used only once**? If yes, show the generated HTML code, so that I can have a look at it

Comment: They are all different. I added html to question.

Comment: I have successfully tested the code. Click at one of the `Edit` links at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSaLT/)**

Comment: Yes, this works. But that is not source of my problem. Bu I now know at last what isn't. I need to start another question. Thanks